# Redirect automatically to the login when the session is expired in spring security 4.1

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I'm using spring 4.1.x and spring security 4.1.x.

I have done an example using spring security, in that when my session is expired then also it allows to access the operations.
I want to redirect to login page when session is expired.
please help me.
thanks regards.

Comment: I'm trying with this but it does not work                                        <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login">
        <sec:concurrency-control expired-url="/login" />
</sec:session-management>

Comment: have you added the httpsessionlistener in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

if you have missed adding the httpsession listener in web.xml .try adding it.

```
 <listener-class>
  org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
</listener-class>
```